# Add legend or background image to Igraph 0.6 (for python) plot

Tags: python, graph, plot, legend, igraph

I plot a graph with python 2.7 by using Igraph 0.6 with the Cairo extention for plotting. All good but I would like to add a legend each time I plot.

If I could only add a background image to the plot that would be also fine, because I make a white image with the right size and with the legend already added there (with general sign explanation).

None of this I can do, nor I can find by googleing it. Maybe I'm just unable to get on the right side of Google or to find the right keyword in Igraph documentations.

gp = Graph(). It's global. Has vertex and edge sequences etc. There are some lists which contain further information about vertexes and edges (in ex.: self.gp_cities, self.road_kind) Here is how I plot:

```
def showitshort(self,event):
    global gp
    layout = gp.layout("kk")
    color_dict = {"1": "red", "20": "blue"}
    visual_style = {}
    visual_style["vertex_size"] = 15
    visual_style["vertex_color"] = ["yellow"]
    visual_style["edge_color"] = [color_dict[elektro] for elektro in self.road_kind]
    visual_style["vertex_label"] = self.gp_cities
    visual_style["layout"] = layout
    visual_style["bbox"] = (4000, 2500)
    visual_style["margin"] = 100
    visual_style["vertex_label_dist"] = 5
    visual_style["vertex_shape"] = "triangle-up"
    plot(gp,**visual_style)
```

The right link I think is enough. Please help a little and Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that you can pass an existing Cairo surface into `plot` and it will simply plot the graph on that surface instead of creating a new one. So, basically, you need to construct a Cairo surface (say, an `ImageSurface`), draw your legend using standard Cairo calls onto that surface, then pass the surface to `plot` as follows:

```
plot(gp, target=my_surface, **visual_style)
```

As far as I know, `plot()` will not show the graph itself when invoked this way; it will simply return a `Plot` object. You can call the `show()` method of the `Plot` object to show it or call the `save()` method to save it into a PNG file.

Comment: Ok, I give it a try. Thank you Tamás once again! :-)

Comment: It is not working, somehow the surface  I pass to the plot becomes independent of the surface where I write the legend.

Comment: OK, it works for me b first drawing the Plot and then calling plot.save("tmp_filename") and surface.flush() before opening the context for the legend.